# Uniinstalling Python 2.7 and Running first program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Someone help me on how to uninstall python 2.7 as well as correcting this error as attached below

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 /Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/intr/simple.py
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Comment: this all makes no sense. Your problem does not seem to involve Python2.7 at all! And you probably *should not* uninstall it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: assuming you're on a mac, your system uses 2.7 so it shouldn't be uninstalled. however, you can have both 2.x and 3.x installed simultaneously. `brew install python@3.7` https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.7

Answer (score 0):

i got a way around it. Just use VSCODE and then python in it. I downloaded Visual studio code then installed a python extension and I was able to code and run python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).